# twig concat two strings to create a variable's name

Tags: symfony, variables, twig, concatenation

For a Symfony and twig project, I need to concat two strings to create a variable name and get variable's data.

Is better with an example :

```
{% for i in 1..data.nbSlider %}
<img src="{{ asset('images/template/accueil/slider/' ~ (data.slider ~ i) ) }}">
{# I need to get {{data.slider1}} information #}
{% endfor %}
```

Thank you for help

Comment: can you elaborate more and explain what u are trying to do ?

Answer (score 1):

if I understand you correctly...

```
{% set variable_3 = 'some_data' %}

{{ attribute(_context,'variable_' ~ 3) }}
```

Please try to use arrays with keys instead of concatenating variable names. It is hard to debug.